# executing getContenResolver().Insert

Tags: java, android

I try to figure out where a getcontentresolver().insert  methode is executed.

when i read the following code :-

```
mNewUri = getContentResolver().insert(
    UserDictionary.Word.CONTENT_URI,   // the user dictionary content URI
    mNewValues                          // the values to insert
);
```

i see here an assignment of mNewuri ,  to the return value of this method and parameter .

my question is :-
by assignning mNewUri , am i simultaniously executing the getContentResolver() method 
and actually inserting a line to the contentprovider/database ?

this form of execution puzzles me , not only for this specific case.

Answer (score 0):

`mNewUri` is the return `Uri` of the method `insert` of contentUri

```
public abstract class ContentProvider implements ComponentCallbacks2 { 

    public abstract Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values);

}
```

Of course you need to extend ContentProvider in order to use insert

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Content Resolver `insert()` method will return the URL of the newly created row. It will be assigned to mNewUri.

Then you may try to execute

```
long _id = ContentUris.parseId(mNewUri)
```

and obtain inserted row id.